# Adding both Integer and Float values into One Map as one parameter in java

Tags: java

I have `Map<Integer, Integer> pickupMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();` Map like this.
I had inserted values like this

```
if(null != qty_1000 && !"".equals(qty_1000))
    pickupMap.put(Integer.parseInt("1000"), Integer.parseInt(qty_1000));
```

Now I want to insert "0.5" in the place of "1000". How to insert these both values. Please answer me.

Comment: As @RohitJain says a Double can also hold an integer so change the generic type of the HashMap

Comment: Change the map to accept Number instead of Integer.

Comment: Can I know the purpose here?

Comment: I have to map these values with database table values.. I have to hold these values only as "1000" and "0.5"

Answer (score 6):

Integers can only represent numbers without decimals. When you have a floating point number, you need the type [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) (high precision) or [Float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) (low precision).

Double, Float and Integer are all extensions of a common base class [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). When you turn your map into a map of Number, you can put Integers, Floats and Doubles into it.

Answer (score -1):

You can insert multiple things in a map(Integer, Float etc).It wont create any problem.

pickupMap.put(Integer.parseInt("1000"), Integer.parseInt("1000"));
pickupMap.put(Float.parseFloat("1000"), Float.parseFloat("1000"));

Comment: a map `Map<Integer, Integer>` will only hold `Integer` as key and value.

Comment: yea...im refering to a map without any type parameters.It will accept all type of objects